# How to make program where user can choose which option to use?

Tags: java

I need to make an app so user can choose different options.

For example, user wanna make a file, and i make a method in class named `makeFile()`, and call it in main, and when he types "FILE", he makes `file.txt` in a folder.
Bud if he types RENAME, he renames the file. So how do i make it work, if he types first RENAME, to actually rename it before option to make a file?

I have a code, where user first needs to pass the `MAKEFILE` option, to get to RENAME.

```
//This is class Citanje

public class Citanje 
{
    private Person p;
    private File file;
    private FileWriter fw;
    private ArrayList<Person> lista;


    public Citanje() throws IOException 
    {
        p = new Person(); 
    }
    public void createDir() throws IOException
    {
        file.mkdir();
        System.out.println("Napravite direktorijum pod nazivom" + file.getName());
    }

    public void delete()throws IOException
    {
        file.delete();
        System.out.println("Uspesno ste obrisali fajl!");
    }
    public void rename()throws IOException
    {
        File oldfile = new File(file.getName());
        File newfile = new File(file.getName());
        if(!oldfile.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("Fajl ne postoji!");
            return;
        }
        if(newfile.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("Fajl vec postoji!");
            return;
        }
        if(oldfile.renameTo(newfile))
        {
            System.out.println("Uspesno ste promenili ime!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Niste uspesno promenili ime...");
        }
    }

//This is main

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Citanje c;
        Scanner sc;
        //OVDE PRAVOM IF-OVE ZA SVE IF DIR1 ONDA DIR IF LIST ONDA LIST ITD
        try 
        {   
            System.out.print("Unesite vrednost: ");
            //OVO JE ZA DIR
            String pattern = "DIR";
            c = new Citanje();
            sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            if(sc.hasNext(pattern))
            {
                c.createDir();
                System.out.println("Uspesno ste kreirali folder!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Unesite drugu vrednost...");
            }

        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unesite pravu vrednost...");
        }
```

I first need to pass the file option to get to delete one.

Comment: just read the input with next() and compare the string values

Comment: "So how do i make it work, if he types first RENAME, to actually rename it before option to make a file?" - you check whether the file exists and if not you tell the user so. Basically you want to make a command line interface (aka cli) so you might want to grab a tutorial on this.

Comment: You have not instantiated the `File` instance. Any operation on it will result in `NPE`